How to deploy a static next js project to FastPanel? Why are wrong file paths created?
I don't understand how to deploy a static next js project to FastPanel?
The main problem is that when deploying a static project, for some reason the wrong file paths (images, JS, CSS) and links to other pages are created and I don't know what to do about it!
I tried different configurations
enter image description here

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
